# `bower list --paths` error: Cannot read property '_release'

Tags: node.js, bower

When I try to list components with paths:

```
e:\Work\Projects\AllDash>bower list --paths
```

I get this error:

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '_release' of undefined
    at StandardRenderer._tree2archy (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\renderers\StandardRenderer.js:417:47)
    at StandardRenderer._list (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\renderers\StandardRenderer.js:174:20)
    at StandardRenderer.end (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\renderers\StandardRenderer.js:39:21)
    at Logger.<anonymous> (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\bin\bower:106:22)
    at Logger.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Logger.emit (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\bower-logger\lib\Logger.js:29:39)
    at C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\lib\commands\index.js:38:25
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\bower\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
```

Please, help me to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran into the same issue. Running `npm update -g bower` fixed it for me.